# jQuery get value from within multiple functions

Tags: jquery, function

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
On `.change` get BMI value from within the function and display as text.

**Current Problems:**
I am unable to receive the `bmitest` value from either function and get the following error within the console.log `undefined`.

Any help would be grateful!

```
  $('#metricupdate').change(metricUpdate); 
  $('#imperialupdate').change(imperialUpdate); 

  // BMI
    var bmitest;
  // Metric Update Function
    function metricUpdate() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var heightval = parseInt($('#height').val());
        var weightval = parseInt($('#weight').val());
        var bmicalc = weightval / (heightval / 100 * heightval / 100); // BMI Formula
        var bmi = Math.round(bmicalc * 1) / 1;
        bmitest = bmi; // BMI Value <-- Value From Here
      }, 10);
    }
  // Imperial Update Function
    function imperialUpdate() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var feet = parseInt($('#feet').val());
        var inches = parseInt($('#inches').val());
        var stone = parseInt($('#stone').val());
        var pounds = parseInt($('#pounds').val());
        var imperialCalc = ((stone*14)+pounds)/((feet*12+inches)*(feet*12+inches))*703; // BMI Formula
        bmitest = imperialCalc.toFixed(1); // BMI Value <-- Value From Here
      }, 10);
    }
  // BMI Value
    $('#bmi').text(bmitest); // <-- Value to Here
    console.log(bmitest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code with the functions metricUpdate() and imperialUpdate()

```html
 $('#bmi').text(bmitest); // <-- Value to Here
    console.log(bmitest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
  $('#metricupdate').change(metricUpdate); 
  $('#imperialupdate').change(imperialUpdate); 

  // BMI
    var bmitest;
  // Metric Update Function
    function metricUpdate() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var heightval = parseInt($('#height').val());
        var weightval = parseInt($('#weight').val());
        var bmicalc = weightval / (heightval / 100 * heightval / 100); // BMI Formula
        var bmi = Math.round(bmicalc * 1) / 1;
        bmitest = bmi; // BMI Value <-- Value From Here
        // BMI Value
        $('#bmi').text(bmitest); // <-- Value to Here
        console.log(bmitest);
      }, 10);
    }
  // Imperial Update Function
    function imperialUpdate() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var feet = parseInt($('#feet').val());
        var inches = parseInt($('#inches').val());
        var stone = parseInt($('#stone').val());
        var pounds = parseInt($('#pounds').val());
        var imperialCalc = ((stone*14)+pounds)/((feet*12+inches)*(feet*12+inches))*703; // BMI Formula
        bmitest = imperialCalc.toFixed(1); // BMI Value <-- Value From Here
        // BMI Value
        $('#bmi').text(bmitest); // <-- Value to Here
        console.log(bmitest);
      }, 10);
    }
```

So you trigger, after evaluating the bmi value, the jquery `.text()` function to set the new value.